# What is the difference between `future` and `async move { future }`?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I'm wondering why changing the code from using a `Future` directly to using it in an `async move` block makes a difference. Passing it to `tokio::spawn` directly yields an error:

```
use std::error::Error;
use tokio::sync::{mpsc::{self, Receiver}, oneshot::Sender};

struct Msg {
    resp: Sender<Vec<u8>>,
}

async fn client_thread(
    mut rx: Receiver<Msg>,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    while let Some(msg) = rx.recv().await {
        msg.resp
            .send(vec![]) // return some data
            .unwrap();
    }
    Ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let (_tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(5);
    
    tokio::spawn(client_thread(rx));

    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:23:5
    |
23  |     tokio::spawn(client_thread(rx)); // <--- Difference is here
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `Unique<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Result<(), Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>`
note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn`
   --> /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.21.0/src/task/spawn.rs:128:20
    |
128 |         T::Output: Send + 'static,
    |                    ^^^^ required by this bound in `tokio::spawn`
```

But changing it to an `async` block makes it compile:

```
tokio::spawn(async move { client_thread(rx) });
```

The return type of `client_thread` is exactly the same as the `main` function, however, which runs with Tokio without any problems. Moreover, the [error type from `reqwest`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.7.2/reqwest/struct.Error.html) implements `Send`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the `Future` in an `async {}` block as you've done makes it compile but doesn't actually run the `Future`. You need to `.await` it:

```
use futures::executor::block_on; // 0.3.12

async fn f(s: &str) {
    println!("ran {}", s);
}

fn main() {
    block_on(f("first"));
    block_on(async { f("second") }); // this doesn't print
    block_on(async { f("third").await });
}
```

```
ran first
ran third
```

Since the future is not ran, it doesn't end up affecting the traits for the `async {}` block and thus can can satisfy the `Send` constraint. You'll have the same issue again with `.await`.

---

In your case, all you need to do is ensure that the future implements `Send` so it can be ran with `tokio::spawn`. The fix is to dictate that the `Error` trait being returned implements `Send`:

```
async fn client_thread(
    mut rx: Receiver<ClientMsg>,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send>> {
    // ...                    ^^^^^^
}
```